unable to use vscode for java development after updating to 1.91.1
I use JDK 11 and after updating vs code to 1.91.1 the java extensions stopped working for jdk-11
I have tried updating the configuration, but it's still not working.
when i try to run a java program or a class it gets stuck at

Java:activating

and it stay like that forever.
Here is my VS Code settings.json
{
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11",
    "java. configuration. runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "/path/to/jdk-8",
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-11",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "/path/to/jdk-17",
        }
    ]
}


VS Code Version: 1.91.1
OS Version:  windows 11
JDK version : 11

Steps to Reproduce:

install VScode with Java jdk-11 (my project is jdk-11 specific.)
install java coding pack 0.4.1
now try opening any any existing java project or any java file and try to run the java class.
the application stops at the same page with a Java:activating.. image on the status bar.

I have referred to every blog and did everything but nothing worked.

"Please fix it at the earliest" it is not appropriate to ask for urgency in [so]. Also note we are not the Support team for Visual Code.

Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code

Hello, is your version at runtime jdk11? You can try clearing the vscode cache. Then reinstall the extension.

tried that aswell but didn't work

The JDK in java.jdt.ls.java.home should be JDK 17 as the minimum to be compatible with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java. Your project could use a different version of the one in java.configuration.runtimes
Also check if java. configuration. runtimes has really spaces in the middle and remove them if so.

I have tried that aswell, even tried clearing cache, My project doesn't work with windows 17 and if i make the JAVA_HOME pointing to 17 my AEM server doesn't start.

I didn't suggest changing JAVA_HOME. Visual Code uses that property in settings.json that I mentioned. Did you update it with the correct path to JDK 17?
